# Static UItableview inside another UItableview static cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a static UItableview stays inside a static UItableview cell but it failed to get the dynamic height for the cell even I have implemented  the functions below,

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

Anything I missed out in my programs?

Answer (score 2):

You should use Constraints in your `UITableViewCell`. If you added Constraints and you want the height of the `UITableViewCell` based on this Constraints add the following to your `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
// set estimatedRowHeight to whatever is the fallBack rowHeight
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
```

You don't need to implement the methods `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have added constraints on the `tableViewCell`. Make sure you don't constraint to the margin and that the elements are constraint on all sides of the cell.

I would get rid of the `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` method and instead add `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100` for example.